# Trying to return dataset from SQL statement with function

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I've been digging on this for most of the day but have so far been unable to find the right answer.  I'm trying to find a way to return the results of a SQL query in a custom function.  All data in our system is both transaction and effective dated, and we are commonly called upon to compare data between two points of time.  Right now I use a WITH clause to pull two different datasets ("Before" and "After").  The problem is that the queries used to create these datasets are very long, and each CTE is basically the same thing just with different effective dates.  I'd like to find a way to create a function that I can pass the effective/transaction dates to for the comparison so I don't have so much redundant logic in my SQL.  Here's the catch - I have read-only access and cannot create any objects in the DB.  I've read that I can use a Declare statement to get around this but just haven't been able to get it right so far.

Here's an example of what I have now.  I've simplified the query greatly so this isn't a complete mess.

```
WITH    effective_date AS ( 
        SELECT  to_date(:EFFDT)                 AS  effdt, 
                to_date(:REPORT_DATE_BEFORE)    AS  report_dt_before, 
                to_date(:REPORT_DATE_AFTER)     AS  report_dt_after

        FROM    dual), 

        election_data_before AS (
        SELECT  *

        FROM                effective_date                  efd

                CROSS JOIN  elections                       e

        WHERE   efd.effdt               >=  e.start_dt
        AND     efd.effdt               <   e.until_dt
        AND     efd.report_dt_before    >=  e.tran_start_dt
        AND     efd.report_dt_before    <   e.tran_until_dt), 

        election_data_after AS (
        SELECT  *

        FROM                effective_date                  efd

                CROSS JOIN  elections                       e

        WHERE   efd.effdt               >=  e.start_dt
        AND     efd.effdt               <   e.until_dt
        AND     efd.report_dt_after     >=  e.tran_start_dt
        AND     efd.report_dt_after     <   e.tran_until_dt)

SELECT  ...

FROM                    election_data_before            edb

        INNER JOIN      election_data_after             eda
                    ON      edb.employee_id         =   eda.employee_id
                    AND     edb.benefit_type        =   eda.benefit_type

WHERE   ...
```

This doesn't look so bad, but like I said this is extremely simplified.  Here's what I'd like to be able to do.  I know this is garbage code, just trying to illustrate what I'm picturing.

```
FUNCTION    elections   (   effdt   date,   report_dt date )
RETURN  (
        SELECT  *

        FROM    elections  e

        WHERE   effdt               >=  e.start_dt
        AND     effdt               <   e.until_dt
        AND     report_dt           >=  e.tran_start_dt
        AND     report_dt           <   e.tran_until_dt)

SELECT  ...

FROM                    elections(:EFFDT, :REPORT_DT_BEFORE)   edb
                    ON      pp.employee_id          =   edb.employee_id

        INNER JOIN      elections(:EFFDT, :REPORT_DT_AFTER)    eda
                    ON      pp.employee_id          =   eda.employee_id
                    AND     edb.benefit_type        =   eda.benefit_type

WHERE   ...
```

I've been reading about pipelined functions and anonymous blocks all day but haven't been able to put it all together.  If anyone can point me in the right direction or let me know if I'm better off just using two different CTEs I'd appreciate it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to create and use a pipelined table function, you must first create an object type.

```
create or replace type election_type as object 
(
  col1 varchar2(100),
  col2 date,
  col3 number       -- Here you define the name and datatype of the columns you want
                    -- to return from the select query.
);
/

create or replace type election_type_tab as table of election_type;
  -- You need a collection (nested table) type to return multiple records 
   -- of the type defined above from your function
```

Now, define your function using an implicit cursor for loop to extract and pass rows to the caller.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_elections (
     effdt DATE,
     report_dt DATE
) RETURN election_type_tab
     PIPELINED
     AS
BEGIN

     FOR rec IN (
         SELECT * --This should return the same columns as that of election_type
          FROM elections e --,some_othertable s
          WHERE effdt     >= e.start_dt AND 
                    effdt < e.until_dt 
          AND   report_dt >= e.tran_start_dt 
            AND report_dt < e.tran_until_dt
     ) LOOP
          PIPE ROW ( election_type(rec.col1,rec.col2,rec.col3) );
     END LOOP;
     return;
END;
/
```

You may then call it like this.

```
 select * from TABLE(fn_elections(sysdate,sysdate+1)); --or some other date argument
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=840e43ee390254799b58cfa0a014bc20)

Comment: With read only access I can't create database objects, so I can't use the CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION.  I read that I have to nest this in an anonymous block, how much does doing this change the solution you've outlined above?